# Easiest way to cut line content and past it inside { }

Tags: cut-copy-paste

I have this

```
subject { }

it 'delete user' do
  expect(BlaBla).to eq ''
  MyModel.my_method
end
```

And I want this

```
subject { MyModel.my_method }

it 'delete user' do
  expect(BlaBla).to eq ''
end
```

**1. First try**

If I do `dd` and then past it inside my bracket with `i<CTRL>r""` I will get something like

```
subject {   MyModel.my_method
}
```

And I have to go in insert mode to past the text and I have to clean some extra space and joins line.

**2. Second try**

I go on the line `wy$` then `"_dd` to remove the line without save it. Then go after the first `{` : `?{<ENTER>lpa<space>`

What will be a better motion to cut only the content of the line store into a register remove the line jump below past inside brackets?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your problem is to repeat the operation in an efficient way you could use a macro:

First put `{` in your search register with `/{`

Then record your macro: ``` qq^DNp``ddq ```

- `qq` record the macro in the q register
- `ma` put a mark on the line you'll delete
- `^` got to the first word of the line (ie. `MyModel`)
- `D` delete the end of the line and put it in the unnamed register
- `N` go to the previous occurence of the search register (`{`)
- `p` put the deleted text between the brackets
- `'a` go to the line you marked before
- `dd`delete the line
- `q` stop the macro recording

Then you'll simply have to go to the next occurence of `MyModel.my_method` and use `@q` to repeate the operation.

Comment: Definitely love the macro version because this is something I do often. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm glad you liked it. There just an important point with this macro version: as it relies on the content of the search register, you might have to check that the register still contains `{` and not something else if you've been doing other stuff between to uses of the macro.

Comment: Rather than jumping back and forth, you can also just delete the line into the black hole: `D"_ddNp` as the macro. (Although I understand you might want to be back where you removed the line when the macro is done.)

Comment: @statox: to avoid the dependance on the search register, maybe have the macro contain : `?{  *}` instead of: `N`

Comment: @dash-tom-bang: You're right, I just assumed that it would be better to go back to the line where you started the macro but it all depends on you're workflow :)

Comment: @OlivierDulac: Yup I wanted to keep the macro more simple but it is possible to make the search within the macro.

Answer (score 7):

You can delete the content of a line (without the line break) with `^d$`. You can delete to any register (e.g. 'l': `"l^d$`.)
If you use that often, I suggest mapping it to a new key:

```
nnoremap D ^d$
```

or

```
nnoremap D "l^d$
```

Note that `^` in difference to `0` does not contain leading whitespace.

Then, within the `{}`, paste it via `p` or `"lp` respectively.

**Additional Note:**

I personally often end up deleting the line after deleting its contents (or more general: deleting something afterwards that should not overwrite my unnamed register). Instead of using registers, for me [this plugin](https://github.com/maxbrunsfeld/vim-yankstack) feels more convenient. It effectively turns your unnamed register into a stack, so you can delete multiple things and when you paste, you can cycle through them.

Comment: Thanks for this version with the plugin. Not sure I will mapping `D` but like your version.

Comment: Thanks! Of course, mappings are something personal, that was only an example to express the idea. ;-) Make yourself familiar with 'mapleader', if you haven't already!

Answer (score 4):

With the cursor on `MyModel.my_method`, I would do:

```
^y$?{<CR>p``dd

^          jump to first printable character
y$         yank the rest of the line
?{<CR>     jump to the opening bracket
p          put what I just yanked
``         jump back
dd         cut the line
```

Answer (score 1):

You might consider doing something like this on the following text: `5G`, `^v$hd`,`?{<cr>`,`p`

```
1  subject { }
2
3  it 'delete user' do
4  expect(BlaBla).to eq ''
5  MyModel.my_method
6  end
```

`5G` gets you to line 5.

`^v$hd` selects the text an line 5 and places it in a register.

`?{<cr>` moves to the nearest `{` prior to line 5.
`p` places the text in the register immediately after the `{` (the current position of the cursor).

Answer (score 1):

For this situations, I have a smart line delete cmd:

```
noremap <silent> <leader>dd ^D"_dd
```

Then you want to paste inside `{ }`. I'm using `?{<ENTER>vi{p`:

```
subject {MyModel.my_method}
```